# Access and change properties of parent object in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I have two classes, the `environment` class has a property of stations which supposed to have multiple instances of the `station` class. I'm trying to add an increase method in the station that will increase the value of the station and will decrease the pending value of the parent environment by the same amount. I've tried to mess around with `super`, `parent` and `Object.getPrototypeOf`, but as I'm new to JavaScript OOP (and to JavaScript by itself) I'm struggling. Any help!

```
class enviroment {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pending = 0;
    this.stations = [];
  }

  newStation(value = 0, name = null) {
    this.stations.push(new station(value, name));
    return this;
  }
}

class station {
  constructor(value = 0, label = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
    this.isTaken = false;
  }

  increase(increasment) {
    this.value += increasment;
    this.parent.pending -= increasment; // <---- HERE
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it by adding a reference for the environment to the stations like:

```
class enviroment {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.pending = 0;
    this.stations = [];
  }

  newStation(value = 0, name = null) {
    this.stations.push(new station(value, name, this));
    return this;
  }
}

class station {
  constructor(value = 0, label = null, environment = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
    this.isTaken = false;
    this.environment = environment;
  }

  increase(increasment) {
    this.value += increasment;
    if(this.environment)
      this.environment.pending -= increasment; // <---- HERE
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Then when I try to convert it to JSON and send it with res.send() (in Express) I get "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON", any ideas what to do?

Comment: Oh I see, is the attribute "name" in environment unique? Maybe you could store only the name inside the station instead of the reference, and then search by the name for the right environment?